# After giving initial admin password in jenkins to Unlock Jenkins i am getting issue

Tags: jenkins

As i am trying to install Jenkins on cloud server and i installed that but after installation when it is asking for the /var/lib/jenkins/secrets/initialAdminPassword i am providing that also but after that i should get a plugin page but i am directly coming into Jenkins home page.

I have tried the installing jenkins again but still i am getting this below error.

**Jenkins root URL is empty but is required for the proper operation of many Jenkins features like email notifications, PR status update, and environment variables such as BUILD_URL.
Please provide an accurate value in Jenkins configuration.**

can any one tell me why this happening.enter image description here